# Menu Button Trouble on Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to use the menu button on the phone but for some reason it is not working? There is no error but the when I press menu it does nothing. I am running a 2.3.3 Android emulator.

Here is my Activity:

```
public boolean onCreatOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

MenuInflater Inflater = getMenuInflater();
Inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){          
        case R.id.MenuClass:
            startActivity (new Intent ("com.clayton.calendar.TOCLASS"));
    return true;

    case R.id.MenuFriends:
        startActivity (new Intent ("com.clayton.calendar.TOFRIENDS"));
    return true;

    default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
}
```

Here is my XML:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/MenuClass"
    android:title="Open Classes"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/MenuFriends"
    android:title="Open Friends"/>
```

Comment: What's not working? Any errors? What have you tried?

Comment: no errors just when I press menu nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater Inflater = getMenuInflater();
    Inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){          
        case R.id.MenuClass:
            startActivity (new Intent ("com.clayton.calendar.TOCLASS"));
            return true;

        case R.id.MenuFriends:
            startActivity (new Intent ("com.clayton.calendar.TOFRIENDS"));
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }   
}
```

(Don't put this inside the `onCreate()` method)

Comment: It does not want me to use the return false in your code. Also it gives me an error for the first Override the new code is above. Not in the onCreate() method

Comment: @user1334858, I think I know where is the problem! Is not `public boolean onCreatOptionsMenu(Menu menu){...}`, it should be `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){...}`. Override this method and it will work (I think). I will edit my answer right now.